# Sort JSON Table alphabetically

Tags: jquery, json, sorting

I want to sort my JSON Table alphabetically by data.model instead of sorting it by fuelState actually. I tested out many things, but actually nothing worked correct ... Is there an easy solution?

```
//..//
<body>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
function callJSON() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.getJSON('./url.php', function(data) {
            $ ("#usertable").empty();

            var cars = data.rec.vehicles.vehicles;
            cars.sort(function(a,b) {
            return parseFloat(b.fuelState) - parseFloat(a.fuelState);
             });
             $.each(cars, function(key, data){
//..//
                $('#usertable').append(
                    function() {
                        return "<tr class="+farbe+">"+
                                    "<td>"+data.model+coopers+"</td>"+
//..//
                                "<tr>"; 
                    }
                );
            })
        }).always(callJSON);
    }, 2000);
    }
    $(callJSON);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Something it tested:

```
    function compare(el1, el2, index) {
    return el1[index] == el2[index] ? 0 : (el1[index] < el2[index] ? -1 : 1);
    }
    var cars = data.rec.vehicles.vehicles;
    cars.sort(function(el1,el2){
    return compare(el1, el2, "data.model")
    });
```

Comment: Check out linq.js, do a google search.  It's a lightweight linq library that you can use in javascript.

Comment: ok ill check it out. Do you now, why my above mentioned solution is not working?

Comment: Look at your code. What `data` (inside `$.each`) is? It is an element of `cars` (you should really change the name). So you should simply do `el1.model` since `el1` is the same as `data`.

Comment: i changed data.model to el1.model  ... Its still not working. Its still not alphabetical..

Comment: @user2718017 No, use this: `cars.sort(function(el1,el2){ return el1.model == el2.model ? 0 : (el1.model < el2.model ? -1 : 1); });`.

Comment: Thank you :) ... thats the solution

Comment: Is there a soultion if i want to sort by fuelState on a second level?